# ViewModel as Observable, Views as Observers of it

Tags: design

Considering i have a Presenter that updates a ViewModel, and potentially multiple Views updatable from this ViewModel.

What would you think about this way to proceed :

Somewhere we register the Views as Observers of the : ViewModel implemented as Observable.
Therefore the Views will automatically be informed when they will have to refresh themselves from the ViewModel they observe.

I think this approach allows the Presenter to be fully decoupled from the Views, and it will keep only one responsibility : just convert the data it receives in an appropriate format for the ViewModel it knows.

Also, if we consider a pulling data (instead of push) approach, the Views would only know the ViewModel as a IMyViewModelObservable by pulling data from it as soon as they are notified on the ViewModel change(s). I prefer this pulling approach, because it allows the ViewModel not to be aware and responsible for what the Views exactly need to be updated. And of course the ViewModel doesn't know anyone, just some Observers of it, whatever it is.

So what would you think about that 2 approaches ? And could you also tell me if you have ever encountered it or them, and in which context ?

Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: Which framework is this in? Because that's how Microsoft style MVVM is intended to be used in XAML apps.

Comment: @pjc50, thanks for your question.
This is not about framework, this is just a will to rethink by myself or together, the possible ways to use a ViewModel relatively to a Presenter and to the View(s). I really talk about Design here, completely agnostic form any technology, it's just about POO and usage of patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I've did it via Observer and got very good results.

The key here is to define a suitable abstract model of view inputs and the adapt your model to them. Sometimes, viewmodel could be declaratively bound to views at the presenter start and no further management was required. However, updates of model from views often can't be done via simple adapters, which limits the application of the approach.

On the other hand, there are frameworks that implement pull approach, where every action causes presenter to refresh all views. One example would be Eclipse Forms. Such approach is error prone (because it is somewhat hard to prevent event and dependency loops) but is more versatile.

Comment: Thanks @Basilevs for sharing your point of View and experience, about these approaches.

About View changes (User actions), i keep them only for the Controller, not for the Presenter. The Controller being an Observer of the View, that it sees as a IMyViewReadable. 
The registration of this Controller as listener of this view, having been done by an another Class, because this is a specific responsibility that chosing who listen to who.

Comment: ...In this approach, the Controller itself mainly only knows 2 types : 
  - the IMyViewReadable, to read View after user event notification (pull approach), and to make call to back-end.
  - the IPresenter (as recipient of the Back-end Response)
here, all the Controller does is, converting the user actions into the appropriate request to the back-end.
I'm a big fan of Dependency Inversion Principle, and try to apply as much as possible the Single Responsibility Principle.